# viewDidAppear from specific view controller

Tags: ios, swift, viewwillappear

I am looking to have some code run when my view controller appears from a specific, other view controller. Something along the lines of this pseudo code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if appearedFromVC == specificVC {
        println("appeared from specificVC")
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have the presented view controller retain the presenting view controller when it is instantiated and then do a class comparison in the viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `BOOL` value like `var isFromSpecificVC: Bool` for the specificVC, and in your `appedaredFromVC` make something like :

```
if speicificVC.isFromSpecificVC == true {
}
```

Also you can add a NSNotification in `appedaredFromVC`,

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "method:", name: "from_specific_view_controller", object: nil)
```

and post this notification when `specificVC` disappear. Good luck : )